# How to check if instance of model exists in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, exists

I have a django app with a basic model (Job). Now in my template I would like to check if an instance exists of that model or not. I want to project a text if there is nothing yet to show, otherwise I'd like to show the model attributes.

Somehow like so (which obviously doesn't work):

```
{% if job.title != "" %}

{{ job.title }}

{% else %}

hola

{% endif %}
```

Also tried:

```
 {% for job in jobs %}

      {% if job.title %}
      {{ job.title }}
      {% else %}
      Hola
      {% endif %}

  {% endfor %}
```

It makes sense it doesn't work because how can I loop through it or return something if it doesn't exist. Is there a simple way to even do that in a template? Or do I have to write my own function? Or what would be a way to do that?

Help is of course very much appreciated

Comment: how are you constructing your `jobs` variable and passing it to the view?

Comment: `{% for ... %} ... {% empty %} ... {% endfor %}` is the construct you want. Check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty)

Comment: that's golden! Exactly what I needed, thanks so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `{% if %}` tag. As [Django doc says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#if):

> The `{% if %}` tag evaluates a variable, and if that variable is “true” (i.e. exists, is not empty, and is not a false boolean value) the contents of the block are output.

So you can do something like this:

```html
{% if job %}

{{ job.title }}

{% else %}

<p>Hi from Uruguay</p>

{% endif %}
```

If you need this inside a for, as @dirkgroten said, you need to use the `{% empty %}` tag. There is [an example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty) in the Django doc.

Comment: thank you very much!! I ended up using the {% empty %} tag, which works exactly like I wanted it. Perfect!!